# Error establishing a database connection on a fresh Wordpress installation

Tags: centos, php, apache-2.4, centos7, wordpress

I've installed a fresh copy of Wordpress on CentOS 7/Apache but am getting the dreaded "Error establishing a database connection" error message when navigating to the site to complete the setup. I've created a new database for Wordpress to use, along with a user which has all privileges on it.

My MySQL (MariaDB) installation is on a separate host, however I can connect to it fine with the command line client:

```
mysqlshow -u <wordpress_db_user> -p -h <host ip>
```

shows `information_schema` and `<wordpress_db_name>` in the list of Databases, and

```
mysql -u <wordpress_db_user> -p -h <host_ip> <wordpress_db_name>
```

opens a session as expected - however there's nothing to query as WP has not set up its tables yet. I've even tried

```
sudo -H -u apache bash -c 'mysql -u <wordpress_db_user> -p -h <host_ip> <wordpress_db_name>'
```

to make sure that SELinux isn't blocking `apache` from connecting.

Is there anything else I can check to get this working? Most of the guides out there stop at "Have you got the right credentials" and "Have you tried repairing the database"...

Answer (score 1):

The answer, as with many things CentOS, is found in SELinux! While the `apache` user *is* able to open network connections, the `httpd` process (regardless of which user it's running as) *isn't* by default. The setting that controls it is `httpd_can_network_connect`, which can be set with

```
setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1
```

Thanks to [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/909999/wordpress-installation-not-accepting-aws-rds-credentials) for helping me to the solution using `audit2why`!

Comment: This allows _all_ outbound traffic, which is probably not what you want. `httpd_can_network_connect_db` will allow database connections.

Comment: Ah thanks, I'll try that.